# pass array into the model

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

How to pass the array into another page?
Example is I have the controller code below

```
 $values = array(
        'RECEIVER_PHYSICAL',
        'RECEIVER_VIRTUAL',
        'EMAIL_TEMPLATE'
        );

    foreach ($values as $id) {
        $data['email'] = $this->mod_rewards->getEmail($id);

    }
```

And this is the model that I want to pass the array

```
public function getEmail($id) {

       $info = $this->core_db->select('*')
                        ->from($this->schema.'.'.$this->v_system_config)
                        ->where("key",$id)
                        ->get();  

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: You don't - you build the array on the other page given there are no variable values in there. And it's not an array - you're just overwriting the same index in an array with 3 different values. And your ORM probably offers a whereIn() method so you can get all the results at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new argument to the method `getEmail`.

```
$values = array(
    'RECEIVER_PHYSICAL',
    'RECEIVER_VIRTUAL',
    'EMAIL_TEMPLATE'
    );

foreach ($values as $id) {
    $data['email'] = $this->mod_rewards->getEmail($id, $values);
}
```

add the argument like this:

```
public function getEmail($id, $values) {
```

though i think there must be something wrong with the design here.

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite your model function as:

```
public function getEmail($id,$array) {

      //use array here
       $info = $this->core_db->select('*')
                        ->from($this->schema.'.'.$this->v_system_config)
                        ->where("key",$id)
                        ->get();  

    return $return;
}
```

While calling this model in controller you need to pass this array.